# MySQL: Slave readonly

Tags: mysql, slave

On a master-slave replication I have some shared tables which are written by master only.

In addition to the shared data, I have some "log tables" which are only relevant for the single machine, not to be shared and not to be backed-up.

If there is no mistake in the application on the server, it will not directly write into the slave machine - except the un-shared log tables.
Isn't it possible to set the readonly flag for the shared tables explicitely? I found some similar questions, but no trustworthy solution yet :-(

Comment: have you looked into setting more explicit grants on the slave so the connecting user is only allowed select grant on those tables.

Comment: OK, limiting the users is possible. A "global" setting overall users who are connected with this slave directly can not be set?

Comment: nope.. you are stuck doing user grants to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whole slave readonly as conf setting: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_read-only